# Why does FUSE readdir returns Input/output error?

Tags: filesystems, fuse

I am seeing a strange issue while implementing the `readdir()` functionality in fuse. Basically when I do `ls` on any directory in fuse, I get an error such as:

> # ls
>   ls: reading directory .: Input/output error
>   file1.c file2.c

But the strange thing is, `readdir()` is doing exactly what it is supposed to do. In the sense that in that particular directory, I have two files named `file1.c` and `file2.c` and it is able to read it correctly.

While debugging the issue I noticed that fuse `filler` function (`fuse_fill_dir_t` passed as an argument to `readdir()` ) is what may be causing this error.

This is because if I simply print the contents of the directory using a debug `printf` without returning the contents using the filler function, I do not see the error.

But as soon as I start using the filler function to return the contents, I start seeing this error.

I have two questions related to this:

1) Anybody have any idea as to why the `filler` function might be causing this problem?

2) How do I look for the definition of the code for the `fuse_fill_dir_t` function? I have looked through most of the fuse functions with that kind of arguments but have had no luck until now.

Any help is appreciated!

Cheers,
Vinay

Answer (score 1):

Such messages may be caused by failed calls to other (possibly unimplemented) FUSE callbacks like `getxattr()`. Then `readdir()` is called and results are obtained right.

You can debug a FUSE filesystem running its executable with key `-d` (debug mode), - that does not daemonize process and prints detailed debug output about FUSE calls.

Also, it would be nice to know what is your platform (Linux/OS X/etc).

Comment: I have the same question in OS X.

Answer (score 0):

I ran across this recently. Be sure to read the comments in `fuse.h` to ensure you are using the filler function correctly:

```
/** Read directory
 *
 * The filesystem may choose between two modes of operation:
 *
 * 1) The readdir implementation ignores the offset parameter, and
 * passes zero to the filler function's offset.  The filler
 * function will not return '1' (unless an error happens), so the
 * whole directory is read in a single readdir operation.
 *
 * 2) The readdir implementation keeps track of the offsets of the
 * directory entries.  It uses the offset parameter and always
 * passes non-zero offset to the filler function.  When the buffer
 * is full (or an error happens) the filler function will return
 * '1'.
 *
 * When FUSE_READDIR_PLUS is not set, only some parameters of the
 * fill function (the fuse_fill_dir_t parameter) are actually used:
 * The file type (which is part of stat::st_mode) is used. And if
 * fuse_config::use_ino is set, the inode (stat::st_ino) is also
 * used. The other fields are ignored when FUSE_READDIR_PLUS is not
 * set.
 */
int (*readdir) (const char *, void *, fuse_fill_dir_t, off_t,
        struct fuse_file_info *, enum fuse_readdir_flags);
```